# How to make Bootstraps Carousel Prev/Next buttons not span entire height of the carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Does anyone know how I might be able to update bootstraps carousel buttons to not span the entire height of the Carousel? I just want the arrows to be present and clickable, not the entire right/left hand area of the carousel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom styling to the css to achieve that.

First, would be to set a specific width/height to the `carousel-control` element so that it doesn't span the entire height of the carousel.

```
.carousel-control {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

After you do this, the background image behind the arrow navigation might look a little off so I would probably hide that as well.

```
.carousel-control.left, 
.carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
}
```

The last step would be to center it vertically on your carousel.

```
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Check out this fiddle I've put up for demo.
https://jsfiddle.net/swsalim/rx5zxd20/2/